# how do I use an ansible string variable that contains jinja delimiters?

Tags: ansible, jinja2

this

```
- name: ugly
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    badstr: "asdf{%jkl"
    mydir: "."
    mydict:
      filea:
        Value:  "blue!42!"
      fileb:
        Value:  "a{%isbad"
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ item.key }}"
        content: "{{ item.value.Value }}"
      loop: "{{ mydict|default({})|dict2items }}"
```

gives me this error:

```
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"msg": "An unhandled exception occurred while templating 'asdf{%jkl'. Error was a <class 'ansible.errors.AnsibleError'>, original message: template error while templating string: Encountered unknown tag 'jkl'.. String: asdf{%jkl"}
```

The 'mydict' structure is returned from a plugin and I do not get to define the members. One of the 'Value's contains a "{%". Any reference to it will cause an error, whether as a variable, file content or in a template.

I have tried all kinds of quoting and combinations of unsafe, {{, %raw, etc. It either gives me the error or puts the name of the variable in the file.

How can I write the value to a file? Or just use it as a variable?

Ansible 2.8.4 on MacOS 11.3, also ansible 2.9 on RHEL 7.

Comment: Please edit your question and add a sample of your data structure with the problematic entry

Comment: Can you provide more details about how these values are set? You say "returned from a plugin"; do you mean an Ansible module?

Comment: I didn't want to get into that because the actual code is snarly. But it's something similar to:
`{{ lookup('aws_ssm', '/PATH/to/params', bypath=true) }}"`
which returns a dict containing the values.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is not in the `copy` task where the values are
evaluated; the problem is how they are being set.  For example, if I
create a simple ansible module named `example.sh` that looks like
this:

```
#!/bin/sh

cat <<EOF
{
    "files": {
    "filea": {
      "Value": "blue!42!"
    },
    "fileb": {
      "Value": "a{%isbad"
    }
    }
}
EOF
```

I can write a playbook like this:

```
- name: ugly
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - example:
      register: mydict

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ item.key }}"
        content: "{{ item.value.Value }}"
      loop: "{{ mydict.files|dict2items }}"
```

And this runs as expected, creating without any errors a file `fileb` with the content:

```
a{%isbad
```

---

Similarly, if I read the data from a JSON file and pass it through `from_json`, it also works fine:

```
- name: ugly
  hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        mydict: "{{ lookup('file', 'data.json')|from_json }}"

    - copy:
        dest: "{{ item.key }}"
        content: "{{ item.value.Value }}"
      loop: "{{ mydict.files|dict2items }}"
```

---

The problem only happens if you define the variables in a context in
which Ansible is looking for Jinja templating  -- so, as the values of
variables in a playbook, a vars file, the arguments to `set_fact`,
etc.

You can potentially work around the problem by changing how you are
consuming these values.

Comment: Fascinating. How is a dict returned by from_json different from other dicts? Is there a flag on it that says "don't template?" Can I set that flag myself? What other lookups/filters do this?
Unfortunately, the dict I have is created by another role, using a lookup that returns the dict. It apparently doesn't have the magic flag or whatever. Is there a way to modify the lookup to fix this?

Comment: It's not about the *return*, it's about where things are *defined*. If you are defining the data some place where Ansible applies templating (in a playbook, in a variables file), you're going to run into that problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `!unsafe` for the variables expected to have these chars. Check this [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_advanced_syntax.html#unsafe-or-raw-strings). when `!unsafe` is used, the string/variable will never get templated.

```
- name: ugly
  hosts: localhost
  vars:
    badstr: !unsafe "asdf{%jkl"
    mydir: "."
    mydict:
      filea:
        Value:  !unsafe "blue!42!"
      fileb:
        Value: !unsafe  "a{%isbad"
  tasks:
    - copy:
        dest: "{{ item.key }}"
        content: "{{ item.value.Value }}"
      loop: "{{ mydict|default({})|dict2items }}"
```

> When handling values returned by lookup plugins, Ansible uses a data
> type called unsafe to block templating. Marking data as unsafe
> prevents malicious users from abusing Jinja2 templates to execute
> arbitrary code on target machines. The Ansible implementation ensures
> that unsafe values are never templated. It is more comprehensive than
> escaping Jinja2 with `{% raw %} ... {% endraw %}` tags.
>
> You can use the same unsafe data type in variables you define, to
> prevent templating errors and information disclosure. You can mark
> values supplied by vars_prompts as unsafe. You can also use unsafe in
> playbooks. The most common use cases include passwords that allow
> special characters like { or %, and JSON arguments that look like
> templates but should not be templated. For example:

```
---
mypassword: !unsafe 234%234{435lkj{{lkjsdf
```

Comment: You did not read the full question. "badstr" is embedded in an object returned by a plugin. I cannot add !unsafe to it.